# Ember inflector and spanish pluralization with a two words name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data (1.0.0-beta.7) with `DS.RESTAdapter` and a spanish API. I have a model call `App.ModuloPerfil` that represents a ternary many to many relationship:

```
App.Perfil = DS.Model.extend({
  nombre: DS.attr(),
  tipo: DS.attr(),
  modulosPerfiles: DS.hasMany('moduloPerfil', { async: true })
});

App.Modulo = DS.Model.extend({
  nombre: DS.attr(),
  alias: DS.attr(),
  tipo: DS.attr(),
  modulosPerfiles: DS.hasMany('moduloPerfil', { async: true })
});

App.ModuloPerfil = DS.Model.extend({
  enabled: DS.attr(),
  perfil: DS.belongsTo('perfil', { async: true }),
  modulo: DS.belongsTo('modulo', { async: true })
});
```

I have defined some inflector rules to deal with the spanish plurals:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('perfil', 'perfiles');
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('moduloPerfil', 'modulosPerfiles');
```

When I make an API request to: `/api/perfil/1` I get the following response:

```
{"perfil": {id: 1, nombre: "Perfil investigador", tipo: "Investigador", modulosPerfiles: [1,2]}}
```

It seems it's all ok so far, but when I check the calls made to the API from the client I see that when it tries to retrieve de `moduloPerfil` element the url is:

```
GET /api/moduloPerfils?ids[]=1&ids[]=2
```

It uses "moduloPerfils", the english plural and not the irregular rule defined in the inflector.

I have tried with `Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('modulo-perfil', 'modulos-perfiles')` but I doesn't work neither.

How the irregular rule must be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing I have discovered the error. It's not a rules problem, the problem was that the `Ember.Inflector` rules **must be declared before** `Ember.Application.create`

I was doing:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('perfil', 'perfiles');
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('moduloPerfil', 'modulosPerfiles');
```

And the correct order is:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('perfil', 'perfiles');
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('moduloPerfil', 'modulosPerfiles');

var App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Sorry, it's a silly mistake.

**FIXED:** Finally this is not an error and the code it's right. The rules can be declared before or after the App creation. The original code works without errors so the problem maybe was another thing that I didn't see.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now, but I'm not sure if that's true, what version of Ember are you using?  I'm asking out of curiosity, since I have an example contradicting that statement http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/463/edit

Comment: I am using Ember 1.5.1 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7. It's strange, you are right. I have modified my code again and now it works with the declarations after de app creation. Maybe there was another problem and I have corrected it without knowing.

Comment: Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I'd recommend updating it, saying it's fixed, but you weren't sure why.  Is it possible the inflector stuff wasn't being included in your build?  Or was maybe a cached js file?